# How to delete photos from Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I wish to delete a photo from my timeline/profile. The directions say "click on options under the photo" and then click delete. There is no delete app and the delete button on my computer does not do it. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Click the photo

   [image: photo in timeline]
2. Click "Options"

   [image: photo view with menus]
3. Click "Delete this photo"

   [image: Options menu]
4. Confirm deletion

   [image: confirm deletion]